# No package available on installing php_odbc on Centos7.9

Tags: centos, php, odbc

I am trying to install php_odbc using yum install. But it shows me the following.

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/x86_64/metalink                                                                           |  39 kB  00:00:00
 * EA4: 103.72.162.35
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 103.72.162.35
 * cpanel-plugins: 103.72.162.35
 * base: mirror.netweaver.uk
 * epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net
 * extras: mirror.launtel.net.au
 * updates: centos.mirrors.telekom.ro
EA4                                                                                            | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
cpanel-addons-production-feed                                                                  | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
cpanel-plugins                                                                                 | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
base                                                                                           | 3.6 kB  00:00:00
epel                                                                                           | 4.7 kB  00:00:00
extras                                                                                         | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
mysql-connectors-community                                                                     | 2.6 kB  00:00:00
mysql-tools-community                                                                          | 2.6 kB  00:00:00
mysql57-community                                                                              | 2.6 kB  00:00:00
updates                                                                                        | 2.9 kB  00:00:00
(1/13): cpanel-addons-production-feed/x86_64/primary_db                                        |  19 kB  00:00:00
(2/13): cpanel-plugins/x86_64/primary_db                                                       |  36 kB  00:00:00
(3/13): epel/x86_64/group_gz                                                                   |  95 kB  00:00:00
(4/13): epel/x86_64/updateinfo                                                                 | 1.0 MB  00:00:00
(5/13): EA4/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                                | 1.4 MB  00:00:00
(6/13): mysql-connectors-community/x86_64/primary_db                                           |  72 kB  00:00:00
(7/13): mysql-tools-community/x86_64/primary_db                                                |  85 kB  00:00:00
(8/13): mysql57-community/x86_64/primary_db                                                    | 258 kB  00:00:00
(9/13): epel/x86_64/primary_db                                                                 | 6.9 MB  00:00:00
(10/13): base/7/x86_64/group_gz                                                                | 153 kB  00:00:00
(11/13): extras/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                            | 224 kB  00:00:00
(12/13): base/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                              | 6.1 MB  00:00:01
(13/13): updates/7/x86_64/primary_db                                                           | 5.6 MB  00:00:03
No package php_odbc available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Tried yum clean all but it shows the same error. Any help is appreciated.

It was a typo with php_odbc and php-odbc. But am still getting no package available.

Edit:
The following is the output for yum repolist

```
    [root@server ~]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 103.72.162.35
 * cpanel-addons-production-feed: 103.72.162.35
 * cpanel-plugins: 103.72.162.35
 * base: miroir.univ-lorraine.fr
 * epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net
 * extras: mirror.aktkn.sg
 * updates: mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in
repo id                                          repo name                                                  status
!EA4/7/x86_64                                    EA4 ( EasyApache 4 )                                        4,017+761
!cpanel-addons-production-feed/x86_64            cPanel Addons Production Feed                                      68
!cpanel-plugins/x86_64                           cPanel Plugins project                                             55
!base/7/x86_64                                   CentOS-7 - Base                                             10,032+40
!epel/x86_64                                     Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64             12,721+803
!extras/7/x86_64                                 CentOS-7 - Extras                                                 451
!mysql-connectors-community/x86_64               MySQL Connectors Community                                        185
!mysql-tools-community/x86_64                    MySQL Tools Community                                             123
!mysql57-community/x86_64                        MySQL 5.7 Community Server                                        484
!updates/7/x86_64                                CentOS-7 - Updates                                            1,635+5
repolist: 29,771
```

Answer (score 1):

The package is called `php-odbc`. There is a hyphen in the name, not an underscore.

```
yum install php-odbc
```

Comment: Am still getting the No package php-odbc available error.

Comment: @Prachi Please add `yum repolist` to your question.

Comment: You have cpanel repos enabled, judging from the output you have posted.  Cpanel often adds a ton of excludes in the yum config, including php*, so you can’t overwrite whatever packages it forces you to use.  That’s why you can’t install anything from the base repos.  Most likely, you will need to ask cpanel for support here, it’s not a CentOS issue.

Comment: @NasirRiley which files do I change the enable line?

Comment: @Prachi After looking again, they are already enabled. What jsbillings said about the Cpanel repos is true and they exclude php packages as not to cause conflicts. If the system needs things from Cpanel, then you can ask them what to do next. If you don't need them, then you can just disable the repos and remove the packages from the exclude line in `/etc/yum.conf` but that's all up to you and what the system is being used for.

Comment: Thankyou @jsbillings and Nasir